# Centos 7, citadel email, server, phpmailer and S/MIME

Tags: php, email, encryption, centos, phpmailer

I already have citadel email server installed on my centos 7 machine. Everything is setup as should be, MX, SPF record etc. When i use phpmailer in my php to send S/MIME encrypted emails to my own gmail account it does not encrypt the message. When i click on view original message I can see that it is signed ( or so I think) by these lines:

```
Content-Type: multipart/signed; protocol="application/x-pkcs7-signature"; micalg="sha1"; boundary="----3CB610479D73F43DC55191B5AECECA87"


This is an S/MIME signed message
```

But at the bottom it adds the file as an attachment.

```
------3CB610479D73F43DC55191B5AECECA87
Content-Type: application/x-pkcs7-signature; name="smime.p7s"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7s"

MIIG0gYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIIGwzCCBr8CAQExCzAJBgUrDgMCGgUAMAsGCSqGSIb3 ............
```

So I am not sure where the problem is. I am starting to think it is citadel server that does not support S/MIME protocol ?

I do use the ->sign( ... ) method in phpmailer before sending and my certificate and key is working because appache is suing them on my website. I did however not set the last parameter of the sign function, even after setting it to the CA chain.crt file it produced the same results as above.

I really want to send encrypted emails, willing to change email servers if necessary. Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

At present PHPMailer does not support S/MIME encryption, only signing. Signed emails are readable without decrypting, but you can verify that their content has not been tampered with. The signature looks like an attachment, and clients that don't understand S/MIME will display it as a generic attachment, so what you're seeing is expected behaviour.

Comment: Synchro himself :) saw your name a lot on phpmailer stackoverflow questions. So from what I understand is that S/MIME encryption and signing is not the same thing ? What i want to do is to decrease the odds of my mail being flagged as spam, so I am under the impression that encrypting with tls aka signing will work, according to google anyway.

Comment: I saw in the Unit tests that your certificate and key files are all in .pem format. Mine is not but ends with .key and .crt for each file irrespective, can this be the problem? I am starting to understand that what I am rather looking for DKIM than signing, to decrease my changes of being classified as spam, is this correct ?

Comment: DKIM and S/MIME signing are very similar. DKIM validates that a message has been sent from a particular system, whereas S/MIME validates that a specific user sent it. You can do both at once, but from an anti-spam points of view, DKIM is probably more useful.

Comment: The file extensions for certs and keys are all a bit random! If you open it in a text editor and it looks like a base64 block with `BEGIN...` and `END...` lines, it's in PEM format.

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate this info. I Understand the difference between S/MIMIE and DKIM now. I will rather try and avoid S/MIME as not not all we based clients support it. Just one more thing if I may. I have been doing research on email encryption for a while now but it is still fuzzy. The little red lock appears next to the mail I send, stating that it was not send using encryption. How do you encrypt mail ? Because i first thought PGP but inspected some of my other mail that i received that was encrypted but it had no sign of PGP headers. So there must be an easy way to encrypt email?

Comment: I also went through the phpmailer documentation and could not find anything on encrypting the mail. Bellow is the header that I want but do not know how to encrypt, so I do not get the last line. 
Received: from ghostfreak.aserv.co.za ...
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id ...
        for ...
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
Is this something I set in phpmailer or on my email server itself?

Comment: That's not encrypted email, that's TLS encryption on the connection.

Comment: Yes I figured. So can i do this in phpmailer or must it be done in my citadel email server?

Comment: If your mail server is configured to use ssl, PHPMailer will use it automatically; you don't have to do anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105544/discussion-between-dr-and-synchro).